# javascript - Transpiling ES6 arrow functions or named functions - what is better?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, transpiler

The ECMAScript 6 standard added many new features to the JavaScript language, including a new [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) notation.

At the moment I transpile my code to es6. Now there are sometimes two options. And I wonder which one is the better.

Use a named function if possible:

```
document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('change', function rotate() {
  rotate(parseInt(this.value, 10));
});
```

Use a arrow function if possible:

```
document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  rotate(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
});
```

Up to know I now this

named function

- It is possible to see the function name in an error stack.

Arrow functions

- Simple syntax.

Are there any other advantages or disadvantages

Comment: *"At the moment I transpile my code to es6."* ES5 you mean?

Comment: Arrow functions don't maintain their own `this` (they grab the `this` from the outer lexical environment) which makes them useful in a bunch of situations (see binding). They also don't have their own `arguments`, but I've yet to find an example where that's been useful in my own work.

Comment: I think this is answered by [*What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) (whose answers include a thorough description of how arrow functions differ from `function` functions).

Comment: You can check the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/452213 and https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My question was which type would I use best if I could use both. 

If I understand it all correctly, then the simpler syntax is the only advantage of an arrow function. If I prefer the named functions, then I can use them as well.

Answer (score -1):

Lexical `this` can be accessed inside arrow functions, they can't access `arguments` and cannot be bound.

Regular functions can access dynamic `this`, `arguments` and can be bound.

The decision which one has to be used as callback is made based on this. If no `this` is involved, arrow function can be used as a rule of thumb.

Most APIs that accept callbacks (e.g. native `addEventListener` and jQuery), provide their context as callback parameter as well, so dynamic `this` isn't needed, and they can be used with arrows.

Some APIs (e.g. D3) don't take this concern into account and need to access dynamic `this`; they should be used with regular functions only and need `self = this` trick to access lexical `this`. A solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661894/3731501) can be used to provide an arrow with expected dynamic `this` as parameter.

Comment: Arrow functions *cannot* access lexical `this`. This is just to help future searchers.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby A more correct wording is that lexical `this` can be accessed inside arrow functions. It really can. Is it wording that bothered you?

Comment: I've never seen `this` return anything other than `undefined` inside an error function.

Comment: I'm no sure what you mean, also there is no mention of error function above. When `this` is accessed inside arrow function, it's retrieved from enclosing lexical context. That's why it's called 'lexical `this`'. In case enclosing context is *global scope* in *strict mode*, `this` will be `undefined`. Otherwise it can be any object. I would suggest to check the reference on this subject, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this