# How to use another class method and the this context in a type method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, dom-events, typescript2.0

I want to rewrite the JavaScript "method" further below in TypeScript.
I am tempted to do it as class, like this:

```
// export default class 
export default class GroupItemMetadataProvider1
{
    protected m_instance;
    protected _grid;
    protected _defaults;

    protected m_options;
    constructor(options)
    {
        this.m_instance = this;
        
        this._defaults = {
            groupCssClass: "slick-group",
            groupTitleCssClass: "slick-group-title",
            totalsCssClass: "slick-group-totals",
            groupFocusable: true,
            totalsFocusable: false,
            toggleCssClass: "slick-group-toggle",
            toggleExpandedCssClass: "expanded",
            toggleCollapsedCssClass: "collapsed",
            enableExpandCollapse: true,
            groupFormatter: this.defaultGroupCellFormatter,
            totalsFormatter: this.defaultTotalsCellFormatter
        };

        options = $.extend(true, {}, this._defaults, options);
        this.m_options = options;
    }

    
    protected defaultGroupCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item)
    {
        if (!this.m_options.enableExpandCollapse)
        {
            return item.title;
        }

        let indentation = item.level * 15 + "px";

        return "<span class='" + this.m_options.toggleCssClass + " " +
            (item.collapsed ? this.m_options.toggleCollapsedCssClass : this.m_options.toggleExpandedCssClass) +
            "' style='margin-left:" + indentation + "'>" +
            "</span>" +
            "<span class='" + this.m_options.groupTitleCssClass + "' level='" + item.level + "'>" +
            item.title +
            "</span>";
    }


    protected defaultTotalsCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item)
    {
        return (columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter && columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter(item, columnDef)) || "";
    }


    protected init(grid)
    {
        this._grid = grid;
        this._grid.onClick.subscribe(this.handleGridClick);
        this._grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(this.handleGridKeyDown);
    }


    protected destroy()
    {
        if (this._grid)
        {
            this._grid.onClick.unsubscribe(this.handleGridClick);
            this._grid.onKeyDown.unsubscribe(this.handleGridKeyDown);
        }
    }


    protected handleGridClick(e, args)
    {
        let context = (<any>this);

        let item = context.getDataItem(args.row);
        if (item && item instanceof Slick.Group && $(e.target).hasClass(this.m_options.toggleCssClass))
        {
            let range = this._grid.getRenderedRange();
            context.getData().setRefreshHints({
                ignoreDiffsBefore: range.top,
                ignoreDiffsAfter: range.bottom + 1
            });

            if (item.collapsed)
            {
                context.getData().expandGroup(item.groupingKey);
            } else
            {
                context.getData().collapseGroup(item.groupingKey);
            }

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }


    // TODO:  add -/+ handling
    protected handleGridKeyDown(e)
    {
        let context = (<any>this);

        if (this.m_options.enableExpandCollapse && (e.which == Slick.keyCode.SPACE))
        {
            let activeCell = context.getActiveCell();
            if (activeCell)
            {
                let item = context.getDataItem(activeCell.row);
                if (item && item instanceof Slick.Group)
                {
                    let range = this._grid.getRenderedRange();
                    context.getData().setRefreshHints({
                        ignoreDiffsBefore: range.top,
                        ignoreDiffsAfter: range.bottom + 1
                    });

                    if (item.collapsed)
                    {
                        context.getData().expandGroup(item.groupingKey);
                    } else
                    {
                        context.getData().collapseGroup(item.groupingKey);
                    }

                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    public getGroupRowMetadata(item)
    {
        return {
            selectable: false,
            focusable: this.m_options.groupFocusable,
            cssClasses: this.m_options.groupCssClass,
            columns: {
                0: {
                    colspan: "*",
                    formatter: this.m_options.groupFormatter,
                    editor: null
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public getTotalsRowMetadata(item)
    {
        return {
            selectable: false,
            focusable: this.m_options.totalsFocusable,
            cssClasses: this.m_options.totalsCssClass,
            formatter: this.m_options.totalsFormatter,
            editor: null
        };
    }
}
```

However, `handleGridClick` & `handleGridKeyDown` both reference the 'this' "event-context", as well as the 'this' class-context to get the options.

Problem is, I can't just bind the this in the constructor, because otherwise, the this-context of the object is wrong. How can I do this?

This is the plain JavaScript variant:

```
// import $ from '../../wwwroot/jQuery-3.3.js';
import Slick from './slick.core.js';

export default GroupItemMetadataProvider;

/***
 * Provides item metadata for group (Slick.Group) and totals (Slick.Totals) rows produced by the DataView.
 * This metadata overrides the default behavior and formatting of those rows so that they appear and function
 * correctly when processed by the grid.
 *
 * This class also acts as a grid plugin providing event handlers to expand & collapse groups.
 * If "grid.registerPlugin(...)" is not called, expand & collapse will not work.
 *
 * @class GroupItemMetadataProvider
 * @module Data
 * @namespace Slick.Data
 * @constructor
 * @param options
 */
function GroupItemMetadataProvider(options)
{
    let _grid;
    let _defaults = {
        groupCssClass: "slick-group",
        groupTitleCssClass: "slick-group-title",
        totalsCssClass: "slick-group-totals",
        groupFocusable: true,
        totalsFocusable: false,
        toggleCssClass: "slick-group-toggle",
        toggleExpandedCssClass: "expanded",
        toggleCollapsedCssClass: "collapsed",
        enableExpandCollapse: true,
        groupFormatter: defaultGroupCellFormatter,
        totalsFormatter: defaultTotalsCellFormatter
    };

    options = $.extend(true, {}, _defaults, options);

    function defaultGroupCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item)
    {
        if (!options.enableExpandCollapse)
        {
            return item.title;
        }

        let indentation = item.level * 15 + "px";

        return "<span class='" + options.toggleCssClass + " " +
            (item.collapsed ? options.toggleCollapsedCssClass : options.toggleExpandedCssClass) +
            "' style='margin-left:" + indentation + "'>" +
            "</span>" +
            "<span class='" + options.groupTitleCssClass + "' level='" + item.level + "'>" +
            item.title +
            "</span>";
    }

    function defaultTotalsCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item)
    {
        return (columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter && columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter(item, columnDef)) || "";
    }

    function init(grid)
    {
        _grid = grid;
        _grid.onClick.subscribe(handleGridClick);
        _grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(handleGridKeyDown);
    }

    function destroy()
    {
        if (_grid)
        {
            _grid.onClick.unsubscribe(handleGridClick);
            _grid.onKeyDown.unsubscribe(handleGridKeyDown);
        }
    }

    function handleGridClick(e, args)
    {
        let item = this.getDataItem(args.row);
        if (item && item instanceof Slick.Group && $(e.target).hasClass(options.toggleCssClass))
        {
            let range = _grid.getRenderedRange();
            this.getData().setRefreshHints({
                ignoreDiffsBefore: range.top,
                ignoreDiffsAfter: range.bottom + 1
            });

            if (item.collapsed)
            {
                this.getData().expandGroup(item.groupingKey);
            } else
            {
                this.getData().collapseGroup(item.groupingKey);
            }

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    // TODO:  add -/+ handling
    function handleGridKeyDown(e)
    {
        if (options.enableExpandCollapse && (e.which == Slick.keyCode.SPACE))
        {
            let activeCell = this.getActiveCell();
            if (activeCell)
            {
                let item = this.getDataItem(activeCell.row);
                if (item && item instanceof Slick.Group)
                {
                    let range = _grid.getRenderedRange();
                    this.getData().setRefreshHints({
                        ignoreDiffsBefore: range.top,
                        ignoreDiffsAfter: range.bottom + 1
                    });

                    if (item.collapsed)
                    {
                        this.getData().expandGroup(item.groupingKey);
                    } else
                    {
                        this.getData().collapseGroup(item.groupingKey);
                    }

                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getGroupRowMetadata(item)
    {
        return {
            selectable: false,
            focusable: options.groupFocusable,
            cssClasses: options.groupCssClass,
            columns: {
                0: {
                    colspan: "*",
                    formatter: options.groupFormatter,
                    editor: null
                }
            }
        };
    }

    function getTotalsRowMetadata(item)
    {
        return {
            selectable: false,
            focusable: options.totalsFocusable,
            cssClasses: options.totalsCssClass,
            formatter: options.totalsFormatter,
            editor: null
        };
    }

    function getOptions()
    {
        return options;
    }


    return {
        init,
        destroy,
        getGroupRowMetadata,
        getTotalsRowMetadata,
        getOptions
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a javascript than a typescript question.

In example 1 you are trying to use a "class pattern", in example 2 you use something like a "closure class" (theres a name for that pattern which I don't remember).

Both patterns are writeable in TS, and I personally prefer to keep "closure class" (example 2). So, you can just keep your code and add type annotations. Turn on `strict: true` and give type annotations to whatever the compiler yells you "has an implicit any type".

**personal opinion ahead**

Pattern nr.2 is usually more maintanable (sources?), pattern 1 is harder to refactor, requires more type annotations, more thinking and gives you room for the `this` binding issue. You'd still want to use pattern 1 on performance intensive things (ex: a game, which seems not to be your case), other than that, pattern 2 is your go. Even classic OOP cases (extend a class and override a method) are easily obtainable through option 2 (option bag pattern).

Typescript's type system is structural -- quite more powerful than "classic" java/C# -- and classes are not nominal in TS. Those are 2 more reasons not to use classes. `class A {}` and `class B {}` or any object are assignable if they have the same properties.

**EDIT: About the this binding issue**

If you really want to stick to ehh... classes...

- You can't have your `this` be 2 things at the same time. If your `this` is your class, then you can find your element through `event.target`. If your `this` was rebound to an element... Oh, well.
- So you'll have to call something like `element.addEventListener("click", Instance.doSomething.bind(this))`. `addEventListener` rebinds your function's `this`. `.bind` says: no.
- Or `element.addEventListener("click", (...i) => Instance.doSomething(...i))`
- If your method is really meant to be called from another `this` context, then write something like

  method(this: HTMLInputElement, x: number, y: string) { }

`this` is nothing more than sort of a hidden function parameter (python and lua explicitly send this as a 1st parameter, for instance), which is overriden by the `onX` calls, which is one of the JS billion-dollar problems, which is one of the reasons why JS classes suck.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I have understood your problem correctly but I think you are saying the event handler is referencing the wrong object.

You need to save your context/scope outside of the event, then you can reference it inside, like this

```
class GroupItemMetadataProvider1
{
    function init(grid)
    {
        let context = this;
        _grid = grid;
        _grid.addEventListener('click', (e, args) => context.handleGridClick(e, args));
        _grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(handleGridKeyDown);
    }

    function handleGridClick(e, args)
    {
        console.log(this); // will reference GroupItemMetadataProvider1
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was already proposed and deleted, he needs access to both the class `this` and the passed in `this`

Answer (score 0):

Use can arrow function that captures `this` from the declaration context, and pass in the event context as an argument using a helper function. The helper function will take the event to subscribe to and will push the subscription in an array to make is simple to unsubscribe from all events.

```
subscriptions: Array<{ unsubscribe: () => any; }> = []
bindAndSubscribe<TArg1, TArg2>(target: {
    subscribe(fn: (e: TArg1, data: TArg2) => any)
    unsubscribe(fn: (e: TArg1, data: TArg2) => any)
}, handler: (context: any, e: TArg1, arg: TArg2) => void) {
    let fn = function (e: TArg1, arg: TArg2) { handler(this, e, arg) };
    target.subscribe(fn);
    this.subscriptions.push({
        unsubscribe: () => target.unsubscribe(fn)
    });

}
protected init(grid: Slick.Grid<any>)
{
    this._grid = grid;
    // note paramters a and e are inffred correctly, if you ever want to add types
    this.bindAndSubscribe(this._grid.onClick, (c, e, a)=> this.handleGridClick(c, e, a));
    this.bindAndSubscribe(this._grid.onKeyDown, (c,e, a) => this.handleGridKeyDown(c,e));
}


protected destroy()
{
    if (this._grid)
    {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(s=> s.unsubscribe());
    }
}



protected handleGridClick(context, e, args)
{ 
    // correct this
    this.m_options.toggleCssClass
    //...
}


protected handleGridKeyDown(context, e)
{
    // Correct this, context is a parameter
    //...
}
```

You can also declare the handlers directly as arrow functions, either approach will work:

```
protected init(grid: Slick.Grid<any>)
{
    this._grid = grid;
    // Arrow function not needed here anymore, the handlers capture this themselves.
    this.bindAndSubscribe(this._grid.onClick, this.handleGridClick);
    this.bindAndSubscribe(this._grid.onKeyDown, this.handleGridKeyDown);
}




protected handleGridClick = (context, e, args) => 
{ 
    // correct this
    this.m_options.toggleCssClass
    //...
}


protected handleGridKeyDown = (context, e) => 
{
    // Correct this, context is a parameter
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [related ES6 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661894/3731501), this problem persists in legacy JavaScript libraries (D3, etc.) that rely on dynamic `this` in event handlers instead of passing all necessary data as arguments.

Same solutions apply to TypeScript as well, with a necessity to maintain type 
safety.

One solution is to use old `self = this` recipe that was deprecated with ES6 arrows but is still needed in this situation and has some smell:

```
handleGridKeyDown(context: DynamicThisType, e: any) {
    // class instance is available as `this`
    // dynamic `this` is available as `context` param
}

...

const self = this;
this._grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function (this: DynamicThisType, e: any) {
  return self.handleGridKeyDown(this, e);
});
```

Another solution is to apply this recipe to certain methods with TypeScript decorator, this also results in a method that has class instance as `this` and dynamic `this` as `context` parameter:

```
function bindAndPassContext(target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const fn = target[prop];

    return {
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            const classInstance = this;
            function wrapperFn (...args) {
                return fn.call(classInstance, this, ...args);
            }

            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                configurable: true,
                writable: true,
                value: wrapperFn
            });

            return wrapperFn;
        }
    };
}

...

@bindAndPassContext
handleGridKeyDown(context: DynamicThisType, e: any) {
    // class instance is available as `this`
    // dynamic `this` is available as `context` param
}


...

this._grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(this.handleGridKeyDown);
```