# `this` direction in vue / typescript / vue-awesome-swiper

Tags: typescript, vue.js, swiper.js

Code

```js
export default class Random extends Vue {
  // data
  public nowIndex: number = -1;
  public swiperOption: Object = {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    slidesPerGroup: 6,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    },
    on: {
      click: function(this: any): void {
        nowIndex = this.clickedSlide.dataset.key;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Question:
Click event's `this` direct to the `Swiper` element , I need it to get a key to tell me which one is being clicked , and I want save this key in vue data ---- nowIndex , but I had a error says **"Cannot find name 'nowIndex'"**

What I do:
I try defined a public value `vue` direct to `this` in the class , but it does not work , the error also says **"Cannot find name 'vue'"**

End:
I hope someone can see this and give me a way out , think you very much TAT .

Comment: *I try defined a public value vue direct to this in the class* - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nowIndex =` is a mistake because there's no `nowIndex` variable, and `nowIndex` class property should always be referred as `this.nowIndex`.

[The documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events) states:

> Please note, that this keyword within event handler always points to Swiper instance

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804309/3731501) explains, this is design problem in a library that relies on `this` in callbacks; a function cannot use component `this` and swiper `this` contexts at the same time. This can be solved either by using `self = this` hack, or by binding function signature to one of these contexts and making it accept another one as a parameter.

This can be done with helper function as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661894/3731501):

```
function contextWrapper(fn) {
    const self = this;

    return function (...args) {
        return fn.call(self, this, ...args);
    }
}

export default class Random extends Vue {
  nowIndex: number = -1;
  swiperOption?: any;

  created() {
    this.swiperOption = { /*...*/
      on: {
        click: contextWrapper((swiperInstance: any) => {
          this.nowIndex = swiperInstance.clickedSlide.dataset.key;
        })
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Or by using a hack, in this case `this` semantics goes wrong:

```
export default class Random extends Vue {
  nowIndex: number = -1;
  swiperOption?: any;

  created() {
    const self = this;

    this.swiperOption = { /*...*/
      on: {
        click(this: any) {
          self.nowIndex = this.clickedSlide.dataset.key;
        })
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for resolve my question . I once try the first solution `self = this` in class like `public vue = this` , but it does not work , could you please teach me where and how can this code work ?

Comment: Will using the suger syntax , I almost forget the `constructor` , this is a big mistake , thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you , I find another question while I'm coding , the `this` in `bindAndPassContext` function bind , is direct to class `Random` not `VueComponent` , so if I update data , view not update , and I can't find a way to put `VueComponent this` in this function

Comment: You didn't specify how exactly you do class inheritance, but I guess this will be so with https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component . The problem with Vue classes is that they aren't really OOP, they are just a syntax for component definition. So my previous comment regarding `constructor` isn't relevant. You need to do this in `created` instead, that's where `self = this` will happen. I updated the post.

Comment: So sorry for this vague question , the answer is perfect resolve my issue , but the relation between `VueComponent` and `Random` still confuse me , is the `@Component` decorator do some work between them ?

Comment: `@Component` class is syntactic sugar for `Vue.extend`, you can check sources. It gets all methods and properties you defined on Random to form a component. Vue component instance isn't an instance of Random.