# is there possible way to bind this to function in events with vue methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
methods:{
    setSwiper() {
        const test = new something;
        test.customEvent('changeEvent', this.handleChange);
    },
    handleChange(){
        console.log(this)// vue instance
    }
}
```

here in method handleChange() I want to access "this" from event

```
methods:{
    setSwiper() {
        const test = new something;
        test.customEvent('changeEvent', function(){
        console.log(this); // event
    });
    }
}
```

is there any possible way to access event from this in vue method? like using bind, apply ...

Comment: *access event from this* what did you want `this` to be exactly? what does the function `customEvent` do? you can bind whatever you want `this` to be in here in line 6 `});` ...e.g. `}.bind(whatever));`

Comment: @JaromandaX at the first code is there possible to access event this in handleChange method? something like test.customEvent('changeEvent', this.handleChange.bind(this));

Comment: The answer likely depends on how `customEvent()` invokes the event handler. Can you show that in the question?

Comment: oh, looks like you want an arrow function for the callback - or as I said already ... `function(){
        console.log(this);
    }.bind(this)`

Comment: This is very specific to `something`. Please, specify the exact library, this will make the question more specific and help other users who use the same library. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600586/this-direction-in-vue-typescript-vue-awesome-swiper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600586/this-direction-in-vue-typescript-vue-awesome-swiper) similar Vue question, this is a common problem with legacy libraries that use dynamic `this` context instead of arguments to supply data to callback functions.

Whenever possible, try to use arguments, some libraries promote the use of `this` but also provide necessary data as arguments:

```
test.customEvent('changeEvent', e => {
  console.log(e); // possibly an event
  console.log(this); // vue instance
});
```

If this is not the case, `self = this` hack can be used:

```
const self = this;

test.customEvent('changeEvent', function () {
  console.log(this); // event
  console.log(self); // vue instance
});
```

A workaround that is compatible with Vue methods that are pre-bound to Vue instance is the use of helper function that passes dynamic context as an argument:

```
function contextWrapper(fn) {
    const self = this; // doesn't matter if used solely with Vue methods

    return function (...args) {
        return fn.call(self, this, ...args);
    }
}

...

setSwiper() {
    const test = new something;
    test.customEvent('changeEvent', contextWrapper(this.handleChange));
},
handleChange(e){
    console.log(e); // event
    console.log(this); // vue instance
}
```