# Avoid targeting the object scope of this inside a function in ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

For instance I am running a project with D3.js, importing specific modules and calling on their functions.

**Setup:**

- TypeScript/ES6
- Importing specific D3 components
- Angular 6

I am having an object, in this case an angular directive, and drawing some circles onto a SVG canvas and want them to trigger a function on a drag event.

**Reduced code snippet:** *Please have a look on `drawPoints()` at the bottom of this snippet*

```
import { ElementRef, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import * as Selection from 'd3-selection';
import * as Shape from 'd3-shape';
import * as Random from 'd3-random';
import * as Drag from 'd3-drag';

import { Config } from './../models/config.model';
import { Point } from './../models/point.model';
import { Param } from './../models/param.model';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCanvas]'
})
export class CanvasDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  private canvas: any;
  private defs: any;
  private gradient: any;
  private svg: any;
  private expandedPoints: Point[];
  private drag: Point;
  public config: Config;

  @Input()
  private param: Param;

  @Output()
  private emitConfig: EventEmitter<Config>;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  private onResize(event) {
    this.init();
  }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.canvas = el.nativeElement;
    this.emitConfig = new EventEmitter();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    intSvg();
    // ..
  }

  private initSvg() {
    if (!this.svg) {
      this.svg = Selection.select(this.canvas).append('svg');
    }
    this.svg
      .attr('width', this.config.width)
      .attr('height', this.config.height);
  }

  private drawPoints(points: Point[]) {
    points.forEach(point => {
      this.svg.append('circle')
        .attr('r', point.color ? 20 : 10)
        .attr('cx', point.x)
        .attr('cy', point.y)
        .attr('fill', point.color ? point.color : 'lightgray')
        .attr('stroke-width', !point.color ? 2 : 0)
        .attr('stroke', !point.color ? 'gray' : '')
        .call(Drag.drag()
          .on('drag', () => {
            // What to call here?
            // Selection.select(this) will not work
            // So how to target the correct „this“?
          }));
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

The problem that occures is not beeing able to reach the correct `this` inside the drag function of the appended circles.

Multiple examples are out there, but they won't work inside the class, because the `this` argument is protected.

*Credits to Mike Bostock's example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older libraries like D3 rely on dynamic `this` context instead of passing all necessary data as arguments and require to use `const self = this` trick to reach lexical `this` in callbacks. The trick is considered obsolete in ES6 but is necessary in such cases. Regular function needs to be used instead of an arrow in order to get dynamic context:

```
private drawPoints(points: Point[]) {
  const self = this;
  ...
    .call(Drag.drag()
      .on('drag', function (this: ProperContextTypeIfNecessary) {
        Selection.select(this);
        // class instance can be referred as `self`
      }));
});
```

It may seem inconsistent that class instance should be referred as `this` in one places and `self` in another ones (this wasn't a problem in ES5 because `self` was supposed to be thoroughly used in such cases for consistency).

As explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661894/3731501), an alternative is wrapper function that will provide callback function D3 context as a parameter, while `this` may still refer to class instance. Arrow functions may be used in this case:

```
function contextWrapper(fn) {
    const self = this;

    return function (...args) {
        return fn.call(self, this, ...args);
    }
}

...

private drawPoints(points: Point[]) {
  const self = this;
  ...
    .call(Drag.drag()
      .on('drag', contextWrapper((d3Context: ProperContextTypeIfNecessary) => {
        Selection.select(d3Context);
        // class instance can be referred as `this`
      }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By avoiding the popular arrow function syntax in ES6 components and using the good old `function() {}` syntax instead, the problem was solved. The arrow functions change the game, because within these called functions it turns out that `this` is not reduced to the called context of the function, but that the context extends globally till the class level.

**Solution:**

```
private drawPoints(points: Point[]) {
  points.forEach(point => {
    this.svg.append('circle')
      .attr('r', point.color ? 20 : 10)
      .attr('cx', point.x)
      .attr('cy', point.y)
      .attr('fill', point.color ? point.color : 'lightgray')
      .attr('stroke-width', !point.color ? 2 : 0)
      .attr('stroke', !point.color ? 'gray' : '')
      .call(Drag.drag()
        .on('drag', function() {
          console.log(this);
        }));
  });
}
```

**Further reading:**

> [...] and ES2015 [ES6] introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own this binding (it retains the this value of the enclosing lexical context).
>   [rwaldron, abasao, martian2049 et. al, *this*, MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)