# React child callback binding this without overriding the original this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChildOnClick = this.handleChildOnClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleChildOnClick() {
    /* I would like to do something here that requires both Child and Parent.
     * But 'this' points to Parent because I binded it in Parent's constructor.
     */
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Child
      onClick={this.handleChildOnClick}
    />)
  }

}
```

In the `handleChildOnClick` callback, I would like to call a Child's method to retrieve some data and update Parent's state accordingly.

If I bind Parent's `this` to  `handleChildOnClick` in Parents constructor, then I lose reference to Child, thus unable to call Child's method. But if I don't bind it, then I'm unable to set Parent's state inside `handleChildOnClick`.

Is there a way to bind `this` while not overriding the original `this` ?

Edit:
My Child component is from a library so I can't modify it.

Edit:
I'm using [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) library. The child component is [GoogleMap](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap), and I would like to store the new view bounds of GoogleMap in Parent's state (by calling `getBounds()` on GoogleMap) whenever the `onBoundsChange` callback of GoogleMap gets fired.

Comment: Better write down your handleChildOnClick(), it would help to find out your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desired `this` is not considered `Child` context. The function is passed as a callback, it's provided with some dynamic `this`. If `this` is `Child` component instance, that's just a coincidence.

The problem is specific to legacy or poorly designed libraries that don't embrace modern JS OOP and rely on arbitrary dynamic `this` instead of passing all necessary data as function arguments. A well-known example is D3 library.

A function cannot have two `this`. A popular workaround is `self = this` trick in conjunction with regular (not arrow) function. However, this becomes clumsy with class syntax because it cannot be placed outside `constructor`:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const self = this;
    this.handleChildOnClick = function handleChildOnClick() {
      // `self` is Parent instance
      // `this` is dynamic context
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Child
      onClick={this.handleChildOnClick}
    />)
  }
}
```

This reshuffle is inconvenient because `this` is usually expected to be class instance in JS OOP.

As explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320230/3731501), a way to address this problem is to provide helper function that performs this trick internally and maps dynamic context to function parameter:

```
function contextWrapper(fn) {
    const self = this;

    return function (...args) {
        return fn.call(self, this, ...args);
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleChildOnClick = contextWrapper(this.handleChildOnClick.bind(this));
  }

  handleChildOnClick(context) {
      // `this` is Parent instance
      // `context` parameter is dynamic context
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Child
      onClick={this.handleChildOnClick}
    />)
  }
}
```

Comment: Eventually I added a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the child component.  Thanks for providing another method to deal with this problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, a ref will work if `this` is specifically Child instance. I didn't check how the library works, but in regular click handlers the first parameter contains all necessary data, this could be the case too. You can check which arguments a handler receives.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call handler in child component from its props and update parent's state:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  handleChildOnClick = (data) => {
    /* I would like to do something here that requires both Child and Parent.
     * But 'this' points to Parent because I binded it in Parent's constructor.
     */
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Child
      handleChildOnClick={this.handleChildOnClick}
    />)
  }

}
```

Then in you child component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {

      handleChildOnClick = () => {
        // you can even send data to parent click handler
        this.props.handleChildOnClick(data); // pass any arguments 
      }

      render() {
        return(
        <button
          onClick={this.handleChildOnClick}
        />)
      }

    }
```

This is how it works in react's pne way binding. 
I hope this would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But the Child component is from a library so I cannot define new functions on it. Is there a solution that doesn't require modifying Child ?

Comment: why do you need two handlers then ? you can child handler and you have declared Child in parent component

Comment: Can you make it more brief in your post and what library you're using